# How to access property in item from a ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am using ngFor directive to iterate over data fetched from SQL back end.  The data is filtered into rows and are structured in a JSON format.

I want to access the value of a property of the CURRENT index in the loop and bind it to the ngModel directive, but when I try, I get the LAST index's value copied into all of my rows.

```
<form #updateRowForm="ngForm" class="update-row-form">
<table mdbTable #tableEl="mdbTable" class="table table-bordered
table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let head of loadedTableData[0] | keys;">{{head}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of loadedTableData; let i = index;">
    <td *ngFor="let property of item | keys;" class="form-group">

    <!--the below will produce undefined for ngModel -->
    <!-- but if I use the below syntax for placeholder attribute, it displays the correct data. Problem is, I need to set this as a default value, hence use of ngModel -->

        <input #editRowProp mdbInput
            [(ngModel)]="item[i][property]"
            class="form-control"
            name="{{property}}"
            placeholder="{{item[property]}}"
            type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" mdbBtn class="btn btn-primary
            rounded
            btn-sm my-0"
            (click)="updateRow(updateRowForm, item)">Update</button>
            <hr>
        <button type="button" mdbBtn class="btn btn-danger
            rounded
            btn-sm my-0" (click)="deleteRow(item)">Remove</button>
    </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Example of data being iterated through:

```
[{TaxCode: "1A", TaxDescription: "testing"},{TaxCode: "A1", TaxDescription: "Costa Rica Baggage Inspection Fee"},{TaxCode: "A6", TaxDescription: "Tunisia Tourism Tax"},{TaxCode: "A7", TaxDescription: "Bolivia Passenger Service Charge"},{TaxCode: "AA", TaxDescription: "Dominican Republic Departure Tax"},{TaxCode: "AB", TaxDescription: "Haiti Airport Departure Tax"}, {TaxCode: "DR", TaxDescription: "Egypt Airport Facility Charge"}]
```

Keys Pipe file:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'keys'
})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    const keys = [];
    for (const key in value) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

Screenshot of what's being returned:

[Repeating property values in ngFor loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pa6l.png)

Comment: what does your data/json look like?

Comment: Shouldn't there only be one item at that level, an index shouldn't be needed. Also, labeling the input like `#editRowProp` loses it's value since there are multiple inputs with the same label

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="loadedTableData[i][property]"`

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="item[property]"` will also work

Comment: @Reactgular  Thanks for you response, I tried that earlier and it ends up repeating the last index's value.  See screenshot I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `item` loop variable already refers to an item of the `loadedTableData` array. You don't need to use an additional index `i` in the `ngModel` binding. You can use `[(ngModel)]="item[property]"`.

Since the input fields are inside a `form`, make sure that each input `name` is unique. One way to achieve that is to combine the loop index `i` and the `property` value in the `name`:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="item[property]" name="{{ 'input_' + property + '_' + i }}" ... >
```

Here is the equivalent property binding syntax:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="item[property]" [name]="'input_' + property + '_' + i" ... >
```

Comment: Each of the inputs being created are given unique names which according to their column names in SQL table.  Here's a screen shot displaying it,  https://imgur.com/a/oD1lgRH

Comment: @Adan - But the names are the same on all rows. You should add the index `i` in the name to make each one unique, as suggested in my answer.

Comment: Aha!  You were correct sir.  By adding the index at the end of each of the unique names, I was able to correctly display the data for each row.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

With the current layout, everything you use in `<td>` correlates to one item that has several properties. The index of the array correlates to `loadedTableData`.

If you use it from this level it would look like `loadedTableData[i][property]`

Comment: As I mentioned to @Reactgular,  I tried that and it ends up repeating the last index's values across all rows. See screenshot I added.

Comment: I upvoted this answer as well ( although it doesn't show ) for nudging me in the right direction.  loadedTableData[i][property]  was the correct selector I needed, but adding unique names to each of the ngModel inputs was the missing link to keep from repeating data.  Thanks !